# Could not load the assembly 'Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=24e9d7d011937483'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, web

A bit of a back story - I am trying to create a custom dispform page for my list in VS2010.  I used instructions [found here to do it](http://thesharepointdive.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/list-forms-deployment-for-sharepoint-2010-part-2-of-4/).  I successfully created the custom form and had the site loading it instead of the default, but am now getting stuck while adding a code behind page.  I am 99% sure the issue is with my namespace and inheritance on the asp page, but I can't for the life of me figure out the issue.  I was hoping someone out her can.  Here's my code:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" CodeBehind="DispRequest.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Inherits="Solvera.SellIT.DispRequest.Solvera.SellIT,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=24e9d7d011937483"  %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

And from the code behind file which is named disprequest.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;


namespace Solvera.SellIT
{
class DispRequest:WebPartPage
{
    protected Button btnSubmitOffer;
    protected TextBox txtOfferAmount;
```

I would greatly appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Thank you,

Comment: check this link out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717814/c-net-how-do-i-find-the-containing-namespace-from-a-class-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `Inherits="Solvera.SellIT.DispRequest.Solvera.SellIT,Version=1.0.0.0,...`

What you probably want is `Inherits="Solvera.SellIT.DispRequest, Solvera.SellIT,Version=1.0.0.0,...`

Where Solvera.SellIT.DispRequest is the fully qualified name of your class, and Solvera.SellIT is the name of the assembly.

You might also need spaces after each comma in the Inherits string, not sure if it matters but that's how mine look.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and received the following error:

Could not load the assembly 'Solvera.SellIT,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=24e9d7d011937483'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that my DispRequest also exists inside a module called Forms.  Does this affect the inherits declaration?

Comment: Did you try with the spacing after the commas, like how the Microsoft assemblies look?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I did try that.  I modified my statement as follows: Inherits="Solvera.SellIT.DispRequest, Solvera.SellIT, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24e9d7d011937483" with spaces after the commas.  This is very frustrating since I believe it should be working.  I would appreciate any other suggestions you might have.

Comment: I also tried just removing the assembly and just left it as  Inherits="Solvera.SellIT.DispRequest" %> but that changed the error to "Could not load type 'Solvera.SellIT.DispRequest'

Comment: I just noticed you copied the PublicKeyToken from the example in the link you provided. That value is unique to your assembly, and the one from the example won't work. In a SharePoint project, it will load `<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>` (a placeholder for the actual string) and `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ApplicationPage1.aspx.cs" Inherits="SharePointProject1.Layouts.SharePointProject1.ApplicationPage1" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>` for a new Application page.

Comment: So is the token then my issue?  I should perhaps recreate my code-behind from scratch again and just modify the inherits string to include my class.  Am I effectively creating a new application page here, just doing it manually and not having Visual Studio do it.  I apologize for my ignorance.  I am still learning a lot of the intricacies here.  Do I need the Version, Culture and PublicKeyToken parameters? Thanks again.

Comment: A way to find the proper string for your assembly is to use the gacutil command, like "gacutil /l Solvera.SellIT" - this should work while you've got your solution deployed, or, there's the $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$ placeholder.

Comment: So I ran the command as you suggested.  It came back with the following:   "Solvera.SellIT, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8f197b7a8502f9c4, processorArchitecture=MSIL".  Should I then set my inherits parameter to: `Inherits=Solvera.SellIT.DispRequest, Solvera.SellIT, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8f197b7a8502f9c4"`?

Comment: lguad: I think we have a winner.  I tried the above and now I am hitting a break point in my code behind.  I thank you very much for your patience and assistance.

Comment: i got the same error but thank god i have sloved it due to this post. just one comma is missing in tag. thank you :)